# Angular Response Interceptor doesn't redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm setting up a global response interceptor to handle redirects for errors. The problem is that the page isn't using the ErrorCtrl nor is the address bar reflecting that the location has been changed. Here's the factory:

```
famaApp.factory('responseObserver', function responseObserver($q, $location) {
    return {
        'responseError': function(errorResponse) {
            $location.path('/error/' + errorResponse.status);
            return $q.reject(errorResponse);
        }
    };
});
```

which is being pushed into $httpProvider's interceptors in app.config:

```
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('responseObserver');
```

I checked the path in the one particular service which was being called as follows:

```
AuthenticationService.authenticate($scope.credentials, function(success) {
    if (success) {
        ...
    } else {
        console.log($location.url());
        ...
    }
});
```

And the $location.url() was correct, /error/502. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit:

I've since update my code and it still doesn't work. Here's my new config:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider',
        function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $location) {
        return {
            responseError: function (response) {
                $location.path('/error/' + response.status);
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    });
    ...
}]);
```

Unfortunately the issue persists.

Comment: Why is your service using a callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing

```
return $q.reject(response);
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try add the "responseError" in the interceptor directly in your app module config. It works for me!

```
var app = angular.module('yourAppName', []);
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $location) {
        return {
            responseError: function (response) {
                $location.path('/error/' + response.status);
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Is unnecessary verify the response.

```
AuthenticationService.authenticate($scope.credentials, function(success) {
    if (success) {
        ...
    } else {
        console.log($location.url());
        ...
    }
});
```

The third argument is the callback error. Is executed when the responses are rejected with "$q.reject".

```
AuthenticationService.authenticate($scope.credentials, function (response) {
    /**
     * Success response
     */
}, function (response) {
    /**
     * Error response
     */
});
```

Comment: I've updated my question - I did what you suggested and I have the same result.